# Help me understand why "молоко готово" and not "молоко готовое"

Tags: грамматика

If I am бел**ый** человек and my wife is бел**ая** and наше молоко бел**ое**...  This much I think I understand quite well!

But with готов I am mystified. Я готов and my wife, готова and the milk, not готов**ое** but merely готов**о**.  She says готов is not an adjective but something else... so can someone kindly explain to me what part of speech "готов" is?

Comment: All of these answers are so helpful, I cannot possibly choose one "best" one.

Answer (score 9):

Готов / готова/готово/ готовы are short forms of adjectives (готовый, -ая, -ое, -ые). Full forms are used attributively, describing a noun. Short forms are used predicatively.

> готовое платье (a ready-made dress), платье готово (the dress is ready).

Answer (score 7):

**Гото́в, гото́ва, гото́во, гото́вы** are short forms of the adjective **гото́вый**. Short forms are used mainly as the predicate in a sentence:

- Снег бел. - The snow is white. (бе́лый)
- Ты уве́рен? - Are you sure? (уве́ренный)
- Ты прав. - You are right. (пра́вый)

Some adjectives are only used in their short forms: **рад** (glad), **до́лжен** (must).

Answer (score 5):

Semantically, this form is a cross-breed between an adjective and a participle. Some centuries ago all adjectives used to have both shortened and elongated forms, now this system is less regular.

You can face the same difference with ***нужен, должен, уверен, рад, прав,*** etc. They are not exactly participles nor adjectives, but a cross-breed of a kind.

The shortened forms (in Neutrum) are used in a one-word sentence, e. g.

***Можно?*** = Can [I]?

***Нужно?*** = [Is it] necessary? [Does [someone / the speaker / the addressee]] have to?

***Готово!*** = [It's] ready! Done!

The difference between ***готово*** and ***готовое*** is that the shortened form used as a kind of perfective (a completed action and/or quality related to a moment of speech), whilest an elongated form refers to an abstract quality.

Comment: Guess, really-really long times ago all adjectives were short-only :-D

Answer (score 2):

I'd hope to add a "thumb rule" here.

There is a meme pattern there, "Long cat is long"
http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=longcat
How should we tell it in Russian?

The direct translation would be "Длинный кот - длинный", (with dash substituting for omitted есть/is verb) but that is quite unnatural, spelling that makes me stress my tongue.

Then we can repeat ourselves, switching to complex sentences: " Длинный кот, он - длинный" ~ "(speaking of a) Long cat, it is long". Which is more verbose but in my opinion is easier to let out.

Typically this is translated as "Длинный кот - такой длинный" aka "Long cat is so long", but that conveys a significantly different mood, I think.

And to my opinion, the most easy to say and most faithful to the language way would be using short adjectives: "Длинный кот длиннен" with the last word fusing two words "is long" in it.

---

There is also another domain: obsolete language idioms, stemming from Middle Ages folklore. Example a semi-rhymed puzzle: "Красна девица // сидит в темнице, // а коса - на улице".

In this example the old idiom "красна девица" is naturally spelled with short adjective. Full adjective and modern word - "красная девушка" - can potentially confuse your listeners.

"На миру и смерть красна" is another example.

Wiki says old Slavic language only had short adjectives, and the full adjectives were developed in Russian language later when it forked from Pra-Slavic family. Perhaps it is true, when I hear other Slavic languages (Serbian, Polish, etc) it seems ot me they exactly only use short adjectives :-D

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85